# How can I create links of my native script app just like a web page? And listen to them?

Tags: http, websocket, nativescript, nativescript-vue

We can perform a specific task when a `URL` is called in the web apps. Suppose we can send an email when a `POST` request just hits a `.php` file.
Exactly the same thing I want to do in `nativescript`. 
So the questions are:

- How can I create links of my apps?
- How can I call them?
- How can it perform an action when a specific `URL` is called from my app?

Actually I'm building a **chat application** which will use `http` calls rather than `socket io`  or `firebase` value change listeners, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for deep linking. Use [nativescript-urlhandler](https://github.com/hypery2k/nativescript-urlhandler/) plugin, setup a URL scheme for your app. Then all you need is just listen to the event and perform navigation for that URL.

Apple started supporting [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) only from iOS 9. You will have to follow some additional steps mentioned in the Apple Docs, basically verify you own the domain.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj . That's what i exactly looking for .
But How can it works with vue js 
Do you have any example or helpful article?

Comment: I Actually want to perform actions on the basis of the Server Side Generated Events Like `firebase` Detect changes or watch for changes like `ref.on('value'.....)` 
Is there any way to implement it
Thanks

Comment: It's better if you do not mix up different topics in one thread. The documentation in the answer will work for Vue too, end of the Vue / Angular / React or any framework NativeScript supports are to reuse the web features in mobile to easily manage / manipulate your UI. The core APIs are same across frameworks.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj i got it :)

Comment: We Can use `nativescript urlhandler` to recive SSE(server send events ) to perform actions on the basis of changings

Comment: No you can't. Technically we don't have SEE because we are not running within a browser. What you do in mobile apps though is, write a background service that will hit your API in intervals Or use sockets if you prefer push instead of post. You may just check the NativeScript docs on background service for more info & how it works.

Comment: But how about Database Calls limit? if i use intervals to hit api
I actually don't want to use sockets 
have you any idea about [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-sse)

Comment: Hmm, good you search for a plugin. Looks like the plugin mimics SSE functionality, you could use that. Also if you are hitting your own DB, I don't think there could be any limitation. If you are using Firebase or any third party, you have to check their docs for limitations on your plan.

Comment: yeah i'm using firebase , so that's why i have the limitation issues. 
Any way thanks for your help , i'll share if some tricks worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a:

```
<Label onTap="clickMe">
```

And the function clickMe add a navigateTo native method.

Comment: Actually i want to create my app reactive like firebase function